# commenting not working in iTerm2 on macOS Big Sur

Tags: terminal, iterm2

I'm using iTerm2(Z shell) on macOS 11.5.2. Because I use certain Perl one-liners (one line of Perl command in a shell application like iTerm2) a lot, it would be a lot easier if adding some comments to the one-liners so I could navigate back to it using the search function of iTerm2.

Normally, it's like `perl path-to-perl-snippet/xxx.pl --an-arg xxx --other-args xxx a.txt #this is doing some task` to do some work with a.txt.

Recently, I clean install the system and find some issues with commenting using `#`, i.e. the content behind `#` is interpreted by the command. This is not what I intend; It should be just comments.

At first, I thought it was a Perl problem. But the simplest command `ls #display list` also has the exact same problem, giving the following error `ls: #display: No such file or directory ls: list: No such file or directory"`

The expected behavior should be like executing `ls` (without the `#display list`) in the iTerm2, which is to display all the files under current directory.

So the real problem probably doesn't lie with Perl. It could be a setting problem with iTerm2 or other settings.

Any suggestions would be helpful. Thank you.

Comment: You have tagged this by _shell_, but I doubt that you are really running a POSIX shell, because if you would, the `#`  would indeed be interpreted as start of a comment in this context. So, be specific and add a tag for the shell you are using. BTW, just being curious - why do you want to have comments in an interactive shell?

Comment: @user1934428 At least in my case, it's not a matter of wanting to write comments, but rather have comments in a copied chunk of a script be ignored when pasted into an interactive shell.

Comment: @jonah_w : You may have updated the post, but I still can not see, which shell you are using.

Comment: @user1934428  I just looked it up. It's Z shell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Newer versions of OS X (as of 10.15 Catalina)](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208050) use the zsh shell by default, which has an "interactivecomments" shell option. It is set "off" by default. Turn it on with:

```
setopt interactivecomments
```

To preserve this setting for future shells, edit that line into your ~/.zshrc file.

The setting is documented in the `man zshoptions` section or online at https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Options.html#index-comments_002c-in-interactive-shells. It is listed there as `INTERACTIVE_COMMENTS`, but the introduction to that section says:

> These names are case insensitive and underscores are ignored. For example, ‘allexport’ is equivalent to ‘A__lleXP_ort’.

This means that you have several ways to enable the option (a partial list):

```
set -o interactivecomments
set -o Interactive_Comments
set -k
setopt interactivecomments
```

as well as disabling it (a partial list):

```
set +o interactivecomments
set +o Interactive_Comments
set +k
setopt nointeractivecomments
```

Answer (score 0):

Whether or not `#` introduces a comment in an interactive shell is controlled by the `interactive_comments` option. It should be enabled by default, but if it has been disabled, run

```
shopt -s interactive_comments
```

Comment: It gives the `command not found: shopt` error.

Comment: I'm using iTerm. Not sure if this is relevant.

Comment: It's not, but my bad for assuming you were using `bash`.

Comment: (Even worse, because I've been using `zsh` as my primary shell for years and have recently been working in an environment where I found it convenient to enable `interactivecomments`.)